# How do i only select Cash and remove the cheque option during txt output

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

Can i get some help please. I have a query as shown below. Right now it shows both cheque and cash. But i want it to show only cash query. Yes, i believe i can edit it(now its vulnerable to SQL Injections)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace MyTestData
{
public partial class frmCollection : Form
{
    public frmCollection()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void dtpFrom_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnExtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection("MYCONNECTION STRING ETCETC");


        SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(10),PaidDate,3)
 AS PaidDate,InvoiceNo,PayerCode,CollectedFee,
( CASE ReceiptTypeID WHEN 'Cash' THEN 'CASH' WHEN 'Check' THEN 'CHEQUE' END ) 
AS ReceiptTypeID FROM InvoicePayment 
WHERE (PaidDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpFrom.Text + "', 105)) AND (PaidDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpTo.Text + "', 105))", objConn);

        SqlDataReader objReader;
        objReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

        System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\CMSExportedData\\Collection-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

        int count = 0;
        while (objReader.Read())
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (!objReader.IsDBNull(i))
                {
                    string s;
                    s = objReader.GetDataTypeName(i);
                    //MessageBox.Show(s);
                    if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "char")
                    {
                        sw.Write(objReader.GetString(i));
                    }
                    else if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "money")

                    {
                        sw.Write(objReader.GetSqlMoney(i).ToString());
                    }
                    else if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "nvarchar")
                    {
                        sw.Write(objReader.GetString(i));
                    }
                    else if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "varchar")
                    {
                        sw.Write(objReader.GetString(i));
                    }

                }
                if (i < 4)
                {
                    sw.Write("\t");
                }

            }
            count = count + 1;
            sw.WriteLine();

        }
        sw.Flush();
        fs.Close();
        objReader.Close();
        objConn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(count + " records exported successfully.");
        this.Close();

    }

    private void frmCollection_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dtpFrom_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

**Edit:** Here is the table structure:

[image]

Here is some sample data:

[image]

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yes sir, i do understand that. It's just a test SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I only wish to see cash

Then remove `WHEN 'Check' THEN 'CHEQUE'` from the `CASE` expression like so:

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(char(10),PaidDate,3) AS PaidDate,InvoiceNo,
  PayerCode, CollectedFee, 
  (CASE ReceiptTypeID 
     WHEN 'Cash'  THEN 'CASH'  
  END ) AS ReceiptTypeID 
...
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(char(10), PaidDate,3) AS PaidDate,
  InvoiceNo, CollectedFee, upper(ReceiptTypeID) AS ReceiptTypeID 
FROM @Invoices 
WHERE (PaidDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '20010101', 105))
  AND (PaidDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '20120101', 105))
  AND ReceiptTypeID IS NOT NULL
  AND lower(ReceiptTypeID) <> 'cheque'
```

### [DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/80926)

Comment: Hi sir, i have tried your method, but it shows a empty where previously they was cheque.

Comment: Hi there, i have edited it to sample data. 
To answer your question. I don't want it to show cheque at all. Even there is cheque, i don't want it to appear in txt. Just cash.

Comment: @Newbie Sorry but I need to see some sample data of what is in there in your tables not the code you are using, please show me some rows from your table and how you want to look like after that query.

Comment: <img src="http://i45.tinypic.com/20ru55g.png" width="100" height="100">

sorry im not sure how i add in picture here to show you. i have linked an external link for your reference sir

Comment: Hi,
I have added sample data. <img src="http://i49.tinypic.com/15ytbmq.png" width="100" height="100">

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17172/discussion-between-newbie-and-mahmoud-gamal)

Answer (score 3):

```
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(10),PaidDate,3) AS PaidDate,InvoiceNo,PayerCode,CollectedFee FROM InvoicePayment WHERE (PaidDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpFrom.Text + "', 105)) AND (PaidDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpTo.Text + "', 105)) AND ReceiptTypeID = 'Cash'", objConn);
```

Notice how I removed the case to show which type it is, and added a clause to the WHERE statement.

Also try to avoid string concatenation in a query, this makes you vulnerable to SQL injection. Try using parameters like;

```
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(10),PaidDate,3) AS PaidDate,InvoiceNo,PayerCode,CollectedFee FROM InvoicePayment WHERE (PaidDate >= CONVERT(datetime, @PAIDDATEFROM, 105)) AND (PaidDate <= CONVERT(datetime, @PAIDDATETO, 105)) AND ReceiptTypeID = 'Cash'", objConn);

SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@PAIDDATEFROM", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpFrom.Text;
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@PAIDDATETO", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpTo.Text;
```